# Share VirtualBox OS through LAN to boot from another PC?

Tags: virtualbox, network-shares, lan, hosts, pxe

In my school, our computers are not really computers (confusing).

We have something like set top boxes that are connected through LAN cable to a huge server that runs Operating systems:

- The server runs Windows Server 2008 for OS, 16 GB RAM, 1 TB HDD, 6-core Intel Xeon.
- It has installed VirtualBox and there are 20 Virtual OS-s.
- Every "set top box" can assign the OS that the user wants.
- The virtual machines runs on the server, but are controlled from the mouse and keyboard that are connected to the set top box.
- These set top boxes (I'm sure they have specific name) are NOT like Mini pc (Intel NUC, Apple Mac Mini and etc.). As far I know they can't run OS itself, they must "assign" from LAN.

-This is how these "boxes" look: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6GEY.jpg and this is what i want to do, but with one cloud computer - http://i00.i.aliimg.com/img/pb/850/292/099/1099292850_421.jpg

I want to do the same at home but only with my powerful PC and my weak netbook.

How can I run directly a virtual machine from my netbook across the LAN? I tried Remote Desktop Connection for both host OS and virtual OS but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're referring to [Remote Virtual Machines](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch07.html), using the VRDP protocol. This (Virtualbox specific) protocol is backwards compatible with Microsoft's RDP protocol. It appears that the "mini pc" you are talking about is actually a [thin client](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_client). Thin clients are often configured to connect to a remote (virtual) desktop environment. In you case, this is a Virtualbox environment on a server, running VRDP.

To create a *similar* situation at home with minimal effort, the easiest way is to connect to your server directly using RDP. Using Google, there are lots of guides telling you how. The advantage is that there is no overhead on your server and no additional software needed, and you can keep running the same OS on your laptop (although you are not using it really).

If you want *the same* situation as on school, you need to install Virtualbox on your server, and follow the steps outlined in [the Virtualbox manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch07.html). You can connect to the Virtualbox server using RDP on your laptop (so no extra software is needed on that side). Since your laptop is not a thin client, directly connecting it to your VRDP server from boot might be possible, but I see no advantage over the "normal" scenario of booting it to Windows and then starting a RDP session.